# React Router v6.4.3 How to navigate in axios interceptors

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to navigate login page when the user token is expired
I catch the error in axios interceptors but I don't have access to router.navigate

I tried to export the createBrowserRouter instance
and import it in the axios file then use the router.navigate("/",{replace:true});
but it doesn't work,

React Router v6.4 doesn't support history

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <ProtectedRoutes />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <Todo />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    element: <LoginPage />,
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    element: <RegisterPage />,
  },
]);

function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    return response;
  },
  function (error) {
    if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
      if (error.response?.status === 401 || error.response?.status === 403) {
        localStorage.clear();
        router.navigate('/', { replace: true });
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: wdym by "outside of react context" 

Comment: React component

Comment: Create axios context and you will have access to the parent context

Comment: From what I understand, using the exported router and `router.navigate` should be valid. What ***exact*** version of `react-router-dom` is installed? You can check by running `npm list react-router-dom`. Can you be more specific about what exactly isn't working? Is there an error message? Is this enough code to be considered a [mcve]? Can we see the router export and import?